# Construct a confidence interval given sample and population size for binary responses... I think

Tags: confidence-interval

If 1,000,000 t-shirts exist in total, and you can track 25% of them (see if they have been purchased or not), and you find that of that 25% half have been purchased, you might believe that half of the total amount of t-shirts have been purchased. Given this 25% sample size, how much deviation from your measured purchase proportion can you expect in the entire population. I'm assuming this could be quantified somehow (with a confidence interval), but don't know how to go about it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Population size = 1,000,000. Sample size = population size * 25% = 250,000.

Finite population correction factor = 1- 25% = 0.75. Point estimate is half of the total amount of t-shirts have been purchased = 50%.

Variance = 0.75 * 0.5 * 0.5 /250,000 = 0.00000075.

So 95 confidence interval is $0.5 \pm 1.96\sqrt{0.00000075} =(49.83\%, 50.17\%)$.

Comment: So I happened to pick half, if I picked 3/5 purchased instead, would the variance be 0.75 * 0.6 * 0.4/250000 ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: And wouldn't the finite population correction factor actually be the square root of what you did? As in ----> sqrt((N-n)/N)

Comment: For variance Var = f $S^2$, SE =$\sqrt f S$. I used f in the var, so do not need sqrt.